# formulário não insere na base de dados

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, formulário

Eu tenho um `HTML` com esse código:

```html
<div class="row">
 <form method="post" action="php/mensagem.php"  accept-charset="utf-8"> 
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<input class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" type="text" required> 
<input class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="email" required>
<input class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" type="text" maxlength="9" required> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
<textarea class="input-xlarge col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="message" name="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem" rows="6" required>            </textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" style="float:left;">Apagar</button>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar" style="margin-top:-39px; float:right"/>
</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

que envia para `PHP` que guarda na bd. com esse código:

```html
<php>
  
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","saber");
  
  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $mail = $_POST['email'];
  $tlm = $_POST['telefone'];
  $msn = $_POST['mensagem'];
  $vista = 0;
  
  $sql = "insert into mensagem(nome,mail,telefone,mensagem,vista) values ('$nome','$mail','$tlm','$msn',$vista)";
  
  if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    echo "<script>
            alert('Mensagem enviada');
            document.location.href = 'index.html';
          </script>";
  }
  else{
    echo "<script>
            alert('Mensagem não enviada');
            document.location.href = 'index.html';
          </script>";
  }
  
?>
```

E quando clico em submit ao invés de inserir e voltar para o index apenas aparece o código

Comment: E o que aparece do alert?

Comment: não aparece nada apenas o código php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente esta acessando a página .html que tem o formulário usando o protocolo `file:///` você deve acessa-la pelo `localhost` assim o código do arquivo .php será executado.

Comment: Que burro que eu fui! Até tenho vergonha de ter feito esta pergunta! Tem toda a razão

Comment: não precisa de pedir já dei e de bom agrado